# Nonconvex optimization problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a *nonconvex* optimization problem with a *linear* objective function, a set of *linear* constraints and a set of nonlinear, non-convex constraints. Is this problem NP-hard? If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: As @Brian Borchers says in his answer, this is impossible to answer without seeing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can show that a class of problems is NP-Hard by taking a known NP-hard problem and reducing it to a problem in your class (being careful that size of the problem does not increase too much.)

Since some well known NP-hard problems can easily be rewritten as nonlinear optimization problems with non-convex constraints, the class of non-convex nonlinear optimization problems is in general NP-Hard.

However, this says nothing about your particular non-convex optimization problem.

Comment: Consider a source-sink flow network that for some nodes in the network, the corresponding outgoing arcs  have unknown inputs that require the amount of flow to such a node must be split based on these coefficients. All unknowns are given in some  intervals. Now, we need to check if there is a realization of the unknowns in the given intervals such that for the corresponding values, the network is feasible.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you've written in the above comment.  I'd suggest editing your original question to describe the problem in detail using mathematical notation.